# Fortran Functions with optional arguments

Tags: function, fortran, option-type

I want to use an operator `.ef.` however the operator does not accept optional arguments. Is it possible to keep the my function and be able to have the operator working too?

```
Module Core
Implicit None

Interface Operator (.ef.)
  Module Procedure fes
End Interface Operator (.ef.)

Contains

Function fes    &
  (             &
    nm, wn      &
  )             &
    Result (located)

Logical :: located
Character (Len=*), Intent (In) :: nm
Character (Len=*), Intent (In), Optional :: wn 

End Function
```

Gfortran is returning the following problem

```
lib/scriptus/core.f:62:0:

Function fes    &
1
Error: Second argument of operator interface at (1) cannot be optional
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not allowed to have optional arguments to defined operations.  Fortran 2008, Cl. 12.4.3.4.2. says:

> 1 ... The dummy arguments shall be nonoptional dummy data objects ...

This is what your compiler is referencing when it emitted the error:

> Error: Second argument of operator interface at (1) cannot be optional

Note: you can have procedures with optional arguments and they can appear in modules, but they cannot be referenced in interface blocks with the `operator` keyword.  Your function `fes` looks fine and it is not the problem.  Your problem is the the interface block mapping an operator to the function.

Comment: @Zeus rather than adding a second question to this one you should ask it as a new question.