# Operator to check file existence

Tags: fortran, operator-keyword

I want to create an operator .f. that checks whether a file exists so that I can write

```
if (.f. filename) Then ...
```

I have already written a function to do this, now have to create the interface. What would  the constraints on e function arguments for having the mentioned functionality?

Comment: You should be able to call stat

Comment: Which bit of this is the problem, as you're not just asking for a code dump?  Is it, "how do I write a function which returns a logical based on the presence of the file?" or "how do I make that function suitable as a unary operator?".

Comment: Please start writing your own code! [Though this sounds silly as I just did that for you...] Rather than outsourcing the work to SO you should do at least a part of the research yourself.

Comment: I had created the function already but needed to set up an operator to work as in the example.

Comment: @Zeus I don't understand... The operator part is **exactly** as you did in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30080094/fortran-functions-with-optional-arguments)?! That reduces the question effectively to "how do I write a function that checks for the existence of a file?" - Just as  francescalus stated.

Comment: That was about the error with the optional part.

Answer (score 10):

You can use the `inquire` intrinsic:

```
module fileIO

interface operator( .f. )
  module procedure file_exists
end interface

contains

function file_exists(filename) result(res)
  implicit none
  character(len=*),intent(in) :: filename
  logical                     :: res

  ! Check if the file exists
  inquire( file=trim(filename), exist=res )
end function

end module

program test
  use fileIO

  print *, file_exists('/dev/null')
  print *, .f. '/dev/null'

end program
```

Comment: Added the operator version. But I agree with  @francescalus in that this is an overkill.

Comment: I agree that with you both that the operator is overkill.  But then I suspect that @Zeus is programming in a much more advanced language than Fortran and using Fortran until a compiler for that other language is available.

Comment: Naturally my function does much more than that. I thought to put a trivial thing that won't freak you out. ;)

Comment: I do some functionality in fortran. I work on extensible  programming where a language can be grown by users. Check Guy Steele's `Growing a Language` at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_ahvzDzKdB0