# Read statement fortran

Tags: gcc, fortran

I am wondering how is it possible to check if the file exists before it is being read by the program to avoid an error during compilation?

I am doing something like that:

```
if (something) then
  open(2,file='test.dat')
  do j=1,1000
    read(2,*)i, told(i)
  enddo
endif
```

How can I add the another `if` statement which stops the program if the file does not exists?

Comment: @ francescalus Yeah that solves my problem, could not find that though. Thanks!

Comment: A little closer to your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30085489/operator-to-check-file-existence/30085587#30085587